Compiling simple DirectX program from command line using VS
I've been trying to compile a simple DirectX program from the command line without success.
I downloaded the examples from https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples opened any project in VS, compiled it and it worked.
Now I wanted to go a little bit lighter and just compile my DirectX program from command line without the need to create a VS project.
I wrote the following command:
"C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.39.33519/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe" ^
    /I "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.39.33519/include" ^
    /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0/um" /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0/ucrt" /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0/cppwinrt" /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0/shared" /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0/winrt" ^
    /I "C:\Users\spl1nes\.nuget\packages\microsoft.direct3d.d3d12\1.613.1\build\native\include" /I "C:\Users\spl1nes\.nuget\packages\microsoft.direct3d.d3d12\1.613.1\build\native\include\d3dx12" /I "C:\Users\spl1nes\.nuget\packages\microsoft.direct3d.d3d12\1.613.1\build\native" ^
    /nologo /W4 /ZI /Od /MDd /GS /EHsc /sdl^
    /D WIN32 /D _DEBUG /D _WINDOWS /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE ^
    /Fo"build/" /Fe"build/main.exe" "src/main.cpp" /Fd"build/main.pdb" ^
    /link ^
    -incremental:no /SUBSYSTEM:windows^
    /LIBPATH:"C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.39.33519/lib/x64" ^
    /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22000.0/um/x64" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22000.0/ucrt/x64" ^
    user32.lib kernel32.lib gdi32.lib winmm.lib d3d12.lib dxgi.lib d3dcompiler.lib dxguid.lib

However, whenever I try to compile the code I get the following FIRST error:
C:\Users\spl1nes\.nuget\packages\microsoft.direct3d.d3d12\1.613.1\build\native\include\d3dx12\d3dx12_property_format_table.h(29): error C3646: 'Layout': unknown override specifier

And many more errors inside the drdx12_property_format_table.h, cstdlib, ... The errors themselves seem nonsensical like this:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\cstdint(20): error C2059: syntax error: 'namespace'

That's why I believe I'm either missing some includes or libs or VS path settings.

Which sample project are you building?

I would recommend using a build system such as CMake to straighten this out. If you already set everything up in a VS Project, setting it up in CMake shouldn't be too difficult.

@MinxinYu-MSFT In VS I tried it with almost all and all worked. From cmd I did the same but for simplicity, let's say HelloBundles

I always do something like if not defined DevEnvDir ( call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat" ) for my CMD build scripts beforehand and then can run cl without specifying the path and can compile MSVC++ syntax fine. I hope that helps. Here is an example bat script using it https://github.com/yosmo78/DirectX12-HandAnimLibOVR/blob/main/Compile.bat

@yosmo78 This helped me to omit some of the "default" includes as these paths are set with vcvars64 (apparently). However I can run your Compile.bat. Are you relying on d3dx12.h? I found out that I can compile as long as I don't use d3dx12.h which of course is annoying.

@DennisEichhorn I do use both #include <d3d12.h> and #include <dxgi1_4.h> (or 1_6 when i wanna use some newer features). I also use #include <dxgidebug.h> in debug and #include <D3Dcompiler.h> when i want to runtime compile shaders. But i don't use d3dx12.h

Alright, after some on and off testing I finally solved it.
It was a problem with the Windows Kit version. I updated to 10.0.26100.0 and it worked.
For example the struct D3D_FORMAT_LAYOUT is not defined in 22000.0. However, the compiler message was a little bit confusing.

Use the x64 Command Prompt for VS2022 tool instead of normal CMD. It will run a script to configure the cl environment.
Take the D3D12Fullscreen for example.

Open the project in Visual Studio : set suppress startup banner:  No in both

Project properties -> C++ -> General and
Linker -> General.
Then build the project so that you can see the build command in Visual Studio and copy it to notepad.

clean the project and build the project from command line .

I removed a part of unnecessary command.  What you need to do is replacing the paths (there are two in this sample): XXX\Downloads\DirectX-Graphics-Samples\XXXX
cl  /I"XXX\Downloads\DirectX-Graphics-Samples-master\Samples\Desktop\D3D12Fullscreen\src\packages\WinPixEventRuntime.1.0.161208001\build\..\Include\WinPixEventRuntime" /ZI /JMC /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /sdl /Od /D WIN32 /D DEBUG /D   _WINDOWS /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline  /Fo"obj\x64\Debug\\"  /external:W3 /Gd /TP /FC /errorReport:prompt D3D12Fullscreen.cpp DXSample.cpp Main.cpp Win32Application.cpp /link "/LIBPATH:XXX\Downloads\DirectX-Graphics-Samples-master\Samples\Desktop\D3D12Fullscreen\src\packages\WinPixEventRuntime.1.0.161208001\build\..\bin" WinPixEventRuntime.lib dxgi.lib d3d12.lib d3dcompiler.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib Delayimp.lib   /DEBUG "/PDB:bin\x64\Debug\D3D12Fullscreen.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/IMPLIB:bin\x64\Debug\D3D12Fullscreen.lib" /MACHINE:X64  "/OUT:bin\x64\Debug\D3D12Fullscreen.exe" 

After building, don't forget to copy postShaders.hlsl , sceneShaders.hlsl , WinPixEventRuntime.dll to exe folder.
Update:
cl  /I"XXX\Downloads\DirectX-Graphics-Samples-master\Samples\Desktop\D3D12HelloWorld\src\packages\Microsoft.Direct3D.D3D12.1.613.1\build\native\include" /I"XXX\Downloads\DirectX-Graphics-Samples-master\Samples\Desktop\D3D12HelloWorld\src\packages\Microsoft.Direct3D.D3D12.1.613.1\build\native\include\d3dx12" /I"XXX\Downloads\DirectX-Graphics-Samples-master\Samples\Desktop\D3D12HelloWorld\src\packages\Microsoft.Direct3D.D3D12.1.613.1\build\native\\" /ZI /JMC /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /sdl /Od /D WIN32 /D _DEBUG /D _WINDOWS /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline  /Fo"obj\x64\Debug\\" /Fd"obj\x64\Debug\vc143.pdb" /external:W3 /Gd /TP /FC /errorReport:prompt Win32Application.cpp D3D12HelloBundles.cpp DXSample.cpp Main.cpp /link d3d12.lib dxgi.lib d3dcompiler.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib Delayimp.lib  /DEBUG "/PDB:bin\x64\Debug\D3D12HelloBundles.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS  "/IMPLIB:bin\x64\Debug\D3D12HelloBundles.lib" /MACHINE:X64  "/OUT:bin\x64\Debug\D3D12HelloBundles.exe"


I tried your update. It couldn't find windows.h. I added the /I to the default includes and I'm back to the same errors starting with d3dx12_property_format_table.h

Did you modify the sample code? Please show the complete errors. It couldn't find windows.h Did you use x64 native tools command prompt for VS?
